# Choose padding size when calculated padding is a non integer

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

In many research papers, downsampling is achieved by the following parameters:

```
kernel_size = 3
Input_size = N
Output_size = N/2
Stride = 2
```

When Calculating Padding using the formula:

```
(Input_size - kernel_size + (2*padding))/Stride +1 = Output_size
```

Padding comes out to be = 0.5

What padding should I choose in such cases (Pytorch)?

Comment: You may round the resulting padding up in such cases. Note that in some situations with equal  padding on all sides and stride >1 the padded edges may not be used. So this effectively results in 0.5 padding. (example: input 8x8, kernel 3x3, stride 2, padding 1)